# Android checkable menu to open up a new class on selection

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-menu

I am creating a menu in Android and I would like this menu to open a new class depending on what the user has selected.

The Menu I have created is from this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog

And is the code for the adding check boxes and radio buttons

I have this code:

```
 final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

But I would like to take the Toast away:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

So when the user clicks on the specified colour in the array list show a new class, which I am not sure how to do.

I am trying to make an if statement that looks like this:

```
  if(items.equals("Red")){
                    Intent red = new Intent(Menu.this,Red.class);
                    startActivity(red);
                }
```

But this doesn't work.

### Edit

No worries I have just done this by doing:

```
if(items[item].equals("Red")){
                    Intent red = new Intent(Menu.this,Red.class);
                    startActivity(red);
                }
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it Ricky:

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
          Intent color;
          switch(item){
          case 0:
           color = new Intent(Menu.this,Red.class);
          break;
          case 1:
           color = new Intent(Menu.this,Green.class);
          break;
          case 2:
           color = new Intent(Menu.this,Blue.class);
          break;
          default:
           color = null;
          break;
          }
          if(color!=null)startActivity(color);
        }
    });
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

good luck.